# Secondary menu sticky to header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed header at the top of the page, and after scrolling down and showing a slider, i have a secondary anchor menu. How can i make this anchor menu get sticky to the header. [image: image shows effect]

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Did you try using [header { position: sticky }](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#CSS_4)?

Comment: Yes i can use Jquery. I never use position sticky

Comment: Sticky is nice but not really supported fully. Position absolute and fixed on the content container should work well. Also I vote to close since it doesn't adhere to standards here at SO.

Comment: Last question for you - does it need to revert to the original position if you scroll back up?

Comment: It dosent need yo revert to his original positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for!

https://codepen.io/will0220/pen/QqreKY

Basically, you need to check the mid-content nav bar's position from the top of the screen, which is done by checking the element's top-offset minus the window's scroll. Then tie in if you're scrolling up or down - so if you're scrolling down, and the mid-page nav is less than your fixed header's height from the top of the screen, clone it and add a fixed version of it. Cloning is the way to go so the content length doesn't change. Then when we scroll in the opposite direction, we can just check where the original in-page nav (which still exists) is, using the same calculation as before.

This'll handle switching in the fixed nav bar:

```
var thisScroll = 0, lastScroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
  thisScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if($('nav').offset().top - thisScroll <= 50 && !$('#stuckNav').length && thisScroll > lastScroll){
    var newNav = $('nav').clone();
    newNav.attr('id', 'stuckNav');
    $('#wrapper').append(newNav);
  }
  else if($('nav').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() > 50 && thisScroll < lastScroll){
    $('#stuckNav').remove();
  }
  lastScroll = thisScroll;
});
```

And the CSS needs something like this:

```
 #stuckNav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}
nav{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: That is perfect

Answer (score 1):

Using just javascript: https://codepen.io/claytron5000/pen/OxZKxB?editors=1010

```js
var secondary = document.querySelector(".secondary");

var fromTop = secondary.offsetTop;

document.onscroll = function() {
  if (!secondary.classList.contains("stuck") && window.pageYOffset >= fromTop) {
    secondary.classList.add("stuck");
  }
  else if (secondary.classList.contains("stuck") && window.pageYOffset < fromTop){
    secondary.classList.remove("stuck");
  }
};
```

```css
.container p {
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
}
.header, .secondary {
  background: beige;
  position: relative;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.stuck {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="header">
    <ul>
      <li>here's</li>
      <li>some</li>
      <li>items</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Some content that will scroll away.</p>
  <div class="secondary">
    <ul>
      <li>here's</li>
      <li>different</li>
      <li>items</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>And a whole lotta ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    Why do we use it?
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    Why do we use it?
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    Why do we use it?
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    Why do we use it?
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    Why do we use it?
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    Why do we use it?
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


    Where does it come from?
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
</div>
```